# Удаление строк из массива

Tags: c, строки

В программе необходимо написать функцию, сравнивающую строки без учета регистра и удаляющую повторяющиеся. Написал функцию, но не могу понять что здесь не так. Как нам избежать ошибки `realloc(): invalid next size`

```
char** lower_and_compare(char** sentences, size_t* sentences_size)
{
    //printf("%s%d", sentences[1], i);
    for(int i=0;i<*sentences_size;i++)
    {
        char *res=sentences[i];    // получение очередной строки
        for(int j=i+1;j<*sentences_size;j++)
        {
            if (strcasecmp(res, sentences[j])==0)
            {
                char** tmp;
                memmove(&sentences[j], &sentences[j+1], sizeof(char*)*(*sentences_size-i-1));      //удаляем нужный элемент
                *sentences_size--;                                                                 //уменьшаем размера массива строк
                if((tmp=realloc(sentences, sizeof(char*)*(*sentences_size)))==NULL)
                {   
                    for(size_t j=0; j<*sentences_size; j++)
                    {
                        free(sentences[j]);   //освобождение памяти из под каждой строки
                    }
                    free(sentences);   //освобождение памяти из под массива со строками
                    return NULL;
                }
                sentences=tmp;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передвигаете память с неправильным размером `*sentences_size-i-1`. Нужно считать от индекса `j`.

Не забывайте ставить скобки и смотреть предупреждения компилятора `warning: value computed is not used` :

```
memmove(&sentences[j], &sentences[j+1], sizeof(char*)*(*sentences_size-j-1));
(*sentences_size)--;
```

Comment: Да, точно, это верно. Но поставив так он же все равно будет выдаст нам ошибку размера.

Comment: Проверьте вторую ошибку : `j` вместо `i`. `memmove(&sentences[j], &sentences[j+1], sizeof(char*)*(*sentences_size-j-1));`

Comment: Да, сработало. Большое спасибо, я вроде это проверял, и всё равно выдавало ошибку. Видимо неправильно проверял :)

Comment: Вы своим неправильным `*(sentences_size--);` смещали ссылку на размер. И по этой причине могло быть полное непредсказуемое поведение проги.